# Нельзя поставить точку в EditText при inputType="numberDecimal"

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть `EditText`, у которого `inputType="numberDecimal"`, пользователь моего приложения у которого телефон `Xiaomi` написал, что у него не ставится точка в этом поле. (то-есть, он не может ввести число типа 0.1) Была ли у кого-то такая ошибка? и знает ли кто-то как исправить такую ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `android:digits="0123456789.,"`